# Storing whois info in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Which format I need to store whois information of a domain in MySQL table?

Like TEXT or BLOB etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [VARCHAR, being that 5.0.3+ supports up to 65,535 characters](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html).  I've seen others have performance issues using TEXT.